# PostgreSQL 9.X bytea representation in 'hex' or 'escape' for thumbnail images

Tags: delphi, postgresql, bytea

My application (developed in Delphi and ZEOS components) uses PostgreSQL 8.4 and stores some thumbnail images into a `bytea` column.

I want to migrate to PostgreSQL 9.2 and have restored the dump and everything works fine except when I try to retrieve those images: Postgres 9.2 uses `hex` for output representation instead of `escape` used in Postgres 8.4.

There are two possible solutions: Change the Postgres 9.2 settings for `escape` representation or change the `hex` string in binary data via application. But what is the best solution? Why did PostgreSQL 9.X change to `hex` for `bytea` representation?
It is a simple setup or are there technical reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rationale was given in the [release notes of Postgres 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-0.html#AEN117209):

> - Allow `bytea` values to be written in hex notation (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> The server parameter `bytea_output` controls whether hex or traditional
>   format is used for `bytea` output. Libpq's `PQescapeByteaConn()` function
>   automatically uses the hex format when connected to PostgreSQL 9.0 or
>   newer servers. However, pre-9.0 libpq versions will not correctly
>   process hex format from newer servers.
>
> The new hex format will be directly compatible with more applications
>   that use binary data, allowing them to store and retrieve it without
>   extra conversion. It is also significantly faster to read and write
>   than the traditional format.

You already seem to be aware of [`bytea_output`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT).