# What's the easiest way to represent a bytea as a single integer in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, casting, converters, postgresql-9.2

I have a `bytea` column that contains 14 bytes of data. The last 3 bytes of the 14 contain the CRC code of the data. I would like to extract the CRC as a single integer to be stored in a new column.

How would I go about doing this?

To clarify, here's one way of doing it in Java:

```
int crc = ((rawData[len - 3] & 0xff) << 16 |
            (rawData[len - 2] & 0xff) << 8 |
            (rawData[len - 1] & 0xff)) & 0xffffff;
```

I'm hoping to find a solution without bit shifting, i.e. something like a method that accepts 4 bytes and converts them into an integer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way is to extract the last 6 characters in `hex` representation, prepend an `x` and cast directly:

```
db=# SELECT ('x' || right('\x00000000000001'::bytea::text, 6))::bit(24)::int;
 int4
------
    1
```

.. which is a bit shorter than the `get_byte()` route, but is also an **undocumented feature** of PostgreSQL. However, I quote [Tom Lane here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2010-11/msg00093.php):

> This is relying on some undocumented behavior of the bit-type input
>   converter, but I see no reason to expect that would break.  A possibly
>   bigger issue is that it requires PG >= 8.3 since there wasn't a text
>   to bit cast before that.

Details in this related answer:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)

This assumes that your setting of `bytea_output` is `hex`, which is the default since version 9.0. To be sure, you can test / set it for your session:

```
SET bytea_output = 'hex';
```

More here:

- [PostgreSQL 9.X bytea representation in 'hex' or 'escape' for thumbnail images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157816/postgresql-9-x-bytea-representation-in-hex-or-escape-for-thumbnail-images)

#### Performance

I ran a test (best of 10) on a table with 10k rows. `get_byte()` is actually a bit faster in Postgres 9.1:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (a bytea);
INSERT INTO t
SELECT (12345670000000 + generate_series(1,10000))::text::bytea;
```

**Bit shifting** is about as fast as multiplying / adding:

```
SELECT 
 ('x' || right(a::text, 6))::bit(24)::int                           -- 34.9 ms
,(get_byte(a, 11) << 16) + (get_byte(a, 12) << 8) + get_byte(a, 13) -- 27.0 ms
,(get_byte(a, 11) << 16) | (get_byte(a, 12) << 8) | get_byte(a, 13) -- 27.1 ms
, get_byte(a, 11) * 65536 + get_byte(a, 12) * 256 + get_byte(a, 13) -- 27.1 ms
FROM t
```

Comment: @CraigRinger: Sometimes the dark side of the force is just too tempting. :)

Comment: Would it not be more efficient to use bit shifting instead of multiplication? See my answer.

Comment: @Zoltán: About the same. I added a test.

Comment: Indeed. I also tested it now. I am accepting your answer because it provides a solution without byte-by-byte operations and shows its inefficiency.

Comment: @Zoltán: For just three bytes, casting is a bit slower. For more bytes (up to 4 for `integer` or 8 for `bigint`, it starts winning since its performance is constant, while the performance of the three alts deteriorates.

Answer (score 5):

```
select get_byte(b, 11) * 65536 + get_byte(b, 12) * 256 + get_byte(b, 13)
from (values ('12345678901234'::bytea)) s(b);
 ?column? 
----------
  3289908
```

Comment: Your example bytea is only 13 bytes long.

Comment: I was wondering why your calculation had different results. You have a typo: 2^16 = **65536**, not 65356.

Answer (score 4):

Well if we're going to do byte-by-byte operations, then bit shifting is probably much more efficient than multiplication.

Based on Clodoaldo Neto's answer I would then say:

```
select (get_byte(arm_data, 11) << 16) |
       (get_byte(arm_data, 12) << 8) |
       (get_byte(arm_data, 13))
            from adsb_raw_message;
```

Does everyone agree?

Comment: Not efficient, but it is much more bit hacking which is in my opinion much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the CRC as a single integer in a separate column, I suggest converting it at insert- or update-time; then persist it together with the value for the `bytea`.

You can do this in your application/business layer or use an insert/update trigger to fill the CRC column.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this in the business layer since the change has been implemented, however, the database already contains a valuable set of data so I was hoping to create a database migration script which would extract the CRC into the new column.